# Content-Type problem with Rails and NIGNX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx

I have a dockerized Ruby-on-Rails application which also uses NGINX.

When I build the containers (using `docker-compose build && docker-compose up`) the containers start, but the CSS and JavaScript files can't be loaded, because their Conten-Type is `text/html`.

What did I configure wrong? I tried several other solutions in the `nginx.conf` but nothing worked.

My configuration:
`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    container_name: trainee_manager_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/app/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - DB_USERNAME=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=postgres
      - DB_PORT=5432
    depends_on:
      - db
  
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: trainee_manager_db
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin

  server:
    container_name: trainee_manager_server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/web/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - 86:80

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: trainee-manager-network

volumes:
  pg_data:
```

`app/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.3

RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install -y make autoconf libtool make gcc perl gettext gperf && git clone https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds.git && cd freetds && sh ./autogen.sh && make && make install

# for postgres
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev

# for nokogiri
RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev

# for a JS runtime
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Setting an Envioronment-Variable for the Rails App
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/trainee_manager
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT

# Setting the working directory
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

# Setting up the Environment
ENV RAILS_ENV='production'
ENV RACK_ENV='production'

# Adding the Gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5 --without development test

# Adding all Project files
COPY . .
RUN bundle exec rake assets:clobber
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "docker/app/entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["docker/app/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-p", "3000"]
```

`app/entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
rm -f /app/tmp/pids/server.pid

bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production

# Then exec the container's main process (what's set as CMD in the Dockerfile).
exec "$@"
```

`web/Dockerfile`:

```
# Base Image
FROM nginx

# Dependiencies
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y install apache2-utils

# Establish where Nginx should look for files
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/trainee_manager

# Working Directory
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

# Creating the Log-Directory
RUN mkdir log

# Copy static assets
COPY public public/

# Copy the NGINX Config-Template
COPY docker/web/nginx.conf /tmp/docker.nginx

# substitute variable references in the Nginx config template for real values from the environment
# put the final config in its place
RUN envsubst '$RAILS_ROOT' < /tmp/docker.nginx > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

`web/nginx.conf:`

```
upstream rails_app {
  server app:3000;
}

server {
  # Defining the Domain
  server_name <SERVERNAME>;
  client_max_body_size 200m;

  # Define the public application root
  root $RAILS_ROOT/public;
  index index.html;

  # define where Nginx should write its logs
  access_log $RAILS_ROOT/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log $RAILS_ROOT/log/nginx.error.log;

  # deny requests for files that should never be accessed
  location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(rb|log)$ {
    deny all;
  }

  # serve static (compiled) assets directly if they exist (for rails production)
  location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets|swfs|system)/ {
    try_files $uri @rails;

    access_log off;
    gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version

    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }

  # send non-static file requests to the app server
  location / {
    try_files $uri @rails;
  }

  location @rails {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://rails_app;
  }

  listen 80;
}
```

Comment: I don't really get it. What does all of these have anything to do with Content-type?

Comment: This is my Problem: I don't know where the Problem is.

Comment: I think the problem lies in your Rail app rather than Docker

Comment: Edited the ordering of the question. People will skip your question completely if they have to scroll way down to even get the gist of your problem. Also "I tried several other solutions..." is completely meaningless information unless you actually tell us what it is you have tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: I tried to include the mime.types on several different points in the nginx config, but this didn't change anything.

Comment: You where right @DoryNguyen, I started the app in development mode and everything worked. Rails is the problem.